# body.scrollTop returns 0 for some sites

Tags: javascript, html

For some pages document.body.scrollTop returns 0, can you help understand why?

For example, https://signup.live.com/signup.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to why the `scrollTop` of the `<body>` remains at `0`, that's because the `<body>` isn't the element that has content scrolling.

That would be instead the `<div id="c_base" class="c_base" ...>` within the page:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('c_base').scrollTop);
// e.g., 500
```

That element is [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to fill the viewport and has [vertical overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) allowing its contents to be scrolled.

```
html.fh .c_base {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: visible;
    position: absolute;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for good explanation! Maybe you can give suggestion, is it possible to get scroll position on page like that without checking the code?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first, just for clarity, `scrollTop` is a property, not a method, so it doesn't return anything. It *is* `0`.

This occurs when either there is no vertical scrollbar (i.e, the entire content fits on the display page), or the scrollbar is already at the top of the element.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop